# Why OS address space must split user space and kernel space?

Tags: kernel, space

In 32-Bit Linux, user space is 3G, and kernel space is 1G. From point of theory, can a kernel and user occupy the 4G address space, when they visit address, they can just visit by their page table.
Is is feasible or why it is unable to implement?

Comment: StackOverflow is not for general questions about computer architecture and OS design. It's for practical programming questions.

Answer (score 2):

It simplifies the kernel greatly to share the address space with the user. Consider a system call that wants to copy data provided by the caller into a kernel buffer. If they each had their own page tables, it would have to switch page tables between reading a word from the caller's buffer and writing it into the kernel buffer:

```
while (i < caller_buffer_length) {
    switch_to_user_pt();
    register = caller_buffer[i];
    switch_to_kernel_pt();
    kernel_buffer[i] = register;
    i++;
}
```

If they're in the same address space, it can simply use `memcpy()`.

Comment: Though note that the kernel has special memcpy functions for working with userspace, to protect from malicious userspace-generated  pointers to kernel addresses as well as segmentation faults.

Comment: @o11c True, but if there were separate address spaces, that special function would have to be written as in my answer.